# Show only first author in citation call-outs

Tags: natbib, author-number

I am using `scrbook` and the `natbib` package. What I basically want to do is that in the reference when using `\citep` only the last name of the first author and the year should be shown no matter how many authors.

For example for the following entry:

```
@ARTICLE{frankenfield2001,
  author = {Frankenfield, D. C. and Rowe, W. A. and Cooney, R. N. and Smith,
    J. S. and Becker, D.},
  title = {Limits of body mass index to detect obesity and predict body composition},
  journal = {Nutrition},
  year = {2001},
  volume = {17},
  pages = {26-3},
  timestamp = {2015.06.16}
}
```

When using `\citep{frankenfield2001}` the output is:

> [Frankenfield et al.,2001]

I want:

> [Frankenfield,2001]

How can this be achieved?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which `\bibliographystyle` are you using?

Comment: What about entries with exactly two authors: Do you still want to show just "(FirstAuthor, year)"? Note that matters of truncation -- in both the citation call-outs and the formatted bib entries -- are generally determined by the bibliography style being used. Hence Torbjorn's earlier query.

Comment: I always want to show only firstAuthor+year and i am using dinat-EN as bibliographystyle. sorry i forgot to mention this :)